# AWS ORACLE to AWS RDS -- Error ORA-01406 even with the InlineLobMaxSize parameter set to 63

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, migration, amazon-rds

I am making a full load of a table with a 9 million rows with a lob column BLOB.
And is about 100G in space, with AWS DMS

With a Full LOB mode it takes an eterniy (More than 2 days).
I tried Inline Mode as sugested in
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/achieve-a-high-performance-migration-to-amazon-rds-for-oracle-from-on-premises-oracle-with-aws-dms/

But I received errors ORA-01406 saying fetched column was truncated from cloudwatch.

I was supposed in InlineMode to treat the  BLOB inline if less than 63 in my case and the others BLOB as FullLOb Mode.

Why these errors messages ?

Regards

With a Full LOB mode it takes an eterniy (More than 2 days).
I tried Inline Mode as sugested in
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/achieve-a-high-performance-migration-to-amazon-rds-for-oracle-from-on-premises-oracle-with-aws-dms/

The error message  Error ORA-01406 shouldn't appear ...

Regards